# How to show values into ListView In android

Tags: android

I am very novice android developer.I am trying to learn the things.I have some values that i was showing in `TextView` but the formatting is not good and values are getting displayed in scattered manner in screen.
Here is my code which is trying to display values into textView..

```
status.setText(("PNR:                    "+pnr+"\n"+
                            "Train No:               "+trainNum+"\n"+
                            "Train Name:             "+trainName+"\n"+
                            "Date Of Journey:        "+date+"\n"+
                            "From Station   :        "+fromname+"\n"+
                            "To Station     :        "+toname+"\n"+
                            "ReservationUpTo:        "+uptoname+"\n"+
                            "Boarding Point :        "+boardtoname+"\n"+
                            "Class          :        "+classvalue+"\n"+
                            "Chart Status   :        "+chartstatus+"\n"+
                            "No Of Passenger:        "+noofpass+"\n"+
                            "Booking Status :        "+booking_status+"\n"+
                            "Current Status :        "+current_status+"\n"
                    ));
```

And here is my design code of ListView In Relativelayout..

```
    <TextView
     android:id="@+id/textView1"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_column="0"
     android:layout_columnSpan="6"
     android:layout_row="6"
     android:gravity="center|bottom"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:textColor="#0f0f0f" />
```

How to change this to `ListView`.Please help me.
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple layout you shouldn't be needing a ListView. Using horizontal LinearLayouts with weights or a single RelativeLayout are more than enough for your question.

But, if you insist on using `ListView`, first you need to learn and understand [ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html)

That is; you can create a List of strings or object, send it to the adapter and set the `Adapter` to your `ListView` and notify it.

There is full guide in [Lars Vogel's website](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html) about implementing ListView and Adapters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use separate text views for the datas/information instead of listview. Or if you want to use listview, create two text views, one will hold the "Train No:" string and another its value.
Put the list of strings like "PNR","Train No:",etc orderwise in an array and its value also in separate array in the same order, and populate it using adapter.

Answer (score 0):

`ListView` is something different than your requirement, I mean `ListView` can't be a choice/option for your requirement.

Instead, I would suggest you to design a layout with `RelativeLayout` and take required number of `TextView` inside it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

 </ListView>Listview simple=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    String[]value=new String[]{"red","blue","white"};
    ArrayAdapter<String>adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,value);
    simple.setAdapter(adapter);
```

This will works for a simple listview